# Vuejs: Cannot resolve module 'fs'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fs

I installed resource-bundle package:

```
npm install resource-bundle
```

But for building:

```
npm run build
```

gets error:
 'cannot resolve module 'fs' '. what should i do?

webpack.base.conf.js:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
   return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
  app: './src/main.js'
  },
 output: {
 path: config.build.assetsRoot,
 filename: '[name].js',
 publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
  : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
},
 resolve: {
 extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src')
}
},
 module: {
  ...
 }
}

node: {
fs: 'empty'
}
```

*added fs: 'empty' at the end.

Comment: You could start by showing the exact steps/commands you tried and the full output of those commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following to your Webpack config:

```
node: {
   fs: "empty"
}
```

Comment: added this at end of webpack.bas.conf.js but still get the same error.

Comment: add inside `module.exports`